# Merge [namedparameterjdbctemplate] and [jdbcnamedparametertemplate]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

The tags [namedparameterjdbctemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/namedparameterjdbctemplate) and [jdbcnamedparametertemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jdbcnamedparametertemplate) seem synonymous. Let's merge them?

Comment: [[tag:namedparameterjdbctemplate]] seems to be the canonical name. I've added a tag wiki to it. I've searched "jdbcnamedparametertemplate" and I get some hits but nothing that confirms its existence. Confusingly, I saw a few articles with "JDBCNamedParameterTemplate " in the title and maybe once in the body but also refer to NamedParameterJdbcTemplate and documentation for it. For example [this article](https://roytuts.com/spring-jdbcnamedparametertemplate-junit-mockito/)

Answer (score 7):

The name of the Spring Framework class is [`NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html).  `JdbcNamedParameterTemplate` doesn't appear to be a thing.

All ten [jdbcnamedparametertemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jdbcnamedparametertemplate) questions should be manually retagged to [namedparameterjdbctemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/namedparameterjdbctemplate), and we should let the misnamed one fade off into the sunset.

Answer (score 5):

Seems pretty clear-cut, especially given that the top Google Search result for "jdbcnamedparametertemplate" is currently...this question.

I generally support the other answer suggesting retagging them all manually, but since I can do it all in one fell swoop without bumping any posts...

```
updating post history, 10 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 10 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 10 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'jdbcnamedparametertemplate': [jdbcnamedparametertemplate] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records for type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records of type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 history records for type Announcement had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records of type Announcement had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 history records for type Collectives Discussion had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records of type Collectives Discussion had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 22
tag remapping of [namedparameterjdbctemplate] and [jdbcnamedparametertemplate] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
1 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
```

I also created a [jdbc-named-parameter-template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jdbc-named-parameter-template) synonym to make searching for the tag a little easier if the person starts by typing "jdbc".

Comment: Me, I always make the hyphenated synonym the canonical one, as losing all case distinction and transition in tag names smashedintoalllowercase sacrifices any hope of reading word boundaries normally. To restore those lost, critical eye-catching edges, introduce an intervening analphabetic character in their stead, here `-`. Why? Because ᴀʟʟ unicameral faces need ꜱᴏᴍᴇ divider to let us perceive word edges—so like [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trajan%27s_Column#Inscription), ɴᴏᴛ [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_uncial_codices#/media/File:Codex_Sinaiticus_Matthew_6,4-32.JPG). 